# Create a column with primary key using migrations

Tags: yii, database-migration, yii-migrations

I am using migrations in Yii to create a new column with. My code works fine however, I am unsure how to set a primary key?

This is a part from my migration file:

```
public function up()
{
    $this->addColumn(
        'competition_prizes',
        'prize_id',
        'INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL FIRST',
    );

    $this->addPrimaryKey('PK1', 'competition_prizes', 'prize_id');
}
```

I don't know, how to make `competition_prizes` column the primary key.

Comment: why has this been downvoted days after an answer was accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working now - did the following:

```
$this->addColumn(
    'competition_prizes',
    'prize_id',
    'INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key FIRST'
);
```

Answer (score 4):

After your `addColumn` function add this line

```
$this->addPrimaryKey('PK1', 'competition_prizes', 'prize_id')
```

Make sure there is no primary key column in your table.

Comment: I'm getting an error - am I doing something wrong-i've modified my original post above.

The error is :-unexpected ')' on line 11 - this is the line with the addPrimaryKey bit

Comment: I think last ',' in your addColumn(). Remove that last `,`

Comment: Superb! Almost there... is it possible to setup AUTO INCREMENT om the the primary key? At the moment the column goes in but it doesn't add increment the value for the primary key by 1 each time.

Comment: please check this url. I'm using this link in my projestc. ypu will get all here.
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbMigration#addColumn-detail

Comment: Cheers will give that a shot

Answer (score 1):

For Yii2 version 2.0.6 - Take a look at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-schemabuildertrait.html#primaryKey%28%29-detail

```
$this->createTable('sometable', [
    'sometable_id' => $this->primaryKey(), // does not depend on Your DBMS
    'sometable_number' => 'SMALLINT(6) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL'// will be depend on your DBMS.
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this

```
$this->addColumn('competition_prizes', 'prize_id', 'pk');
```

'pk' will translate to 'int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY' [Yii2 QueryBuilder Column Type](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-querybuilder.html#getColumnType()-detail)

Answer (score 0):

Use constructer. At the begining of file add

```
use yii\db\Schema;
```

And then add:

```
$this->addColumn(
    'competition_prizes'=> Schema::TYPE_PK,
    'prize_id'=> Schema::TYPE:INTEGER,
);
```